# How to remove set of Json Object based on condition in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a Json file which holds data like:

```
[
  {
    "applicationName": "ABC",
    "machineName": "XYZ",
    "OrderNumber": "N46464646"
  },
  {
    "applicationName": "DEF",
    "machineName": "XYZ",
    "OrderNumber": "D46364636"
  },
  {
    "applicationName": "ABC",
    "machineName": "XYZ",
    "OrderNumber": "D34343434"
  }
]
```

I want to remove a set of object from the above data based on Order Number for eg: If I give order number "D46364636", it should remove-

```
{
    "applicationName": "DEF",
    "machineName": "XYZ",
    "OrderNumber": "D46364636"
}
```

I have tried it doing like this-

```
JsonDataList = new List<JsonItem>();
                string input = "";
                string inputApplicationName = "";
                string inputMachineName = "";
                string inputOrderNum = "";
                while (input != "q")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Press 'd' to Delete item");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to Quit Program");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Command:");
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                    switch (input)
                    {
                        case "d":
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter Order Number to remove:");
                            inputOrderNum = Console.ReadLine();
                            var js = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\ab54253\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\JSONExample\JSONExample\JsonData\AutomatedJson.json");
                            var result=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonData>>(js);
                            foreach(var item in result)
                            {
                                if(item.OrderNumber==inputOrderNum)
                                {
                                    JsonDataList.Remove(new JsonItem(item.applicationName, item.machineName, item.OrderNumber));
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case "q":
                            Console.WriteLine("Quit Program");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Command, Try Again");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Rewriting AutomatedJson.json");
                string JD = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonDataList, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\ab54253\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\JSONExample\JSONExample\JsonData\AutomatedJson.json", JD);
                Console.ReadLine();
```

I am able to check with the condition and I used to remove data by using:

```
if(item.OrderNumber==inputOrderNum)
{
  JsonDataList.Remove(new JsonItem(item.applicationName, item.machineName, item.OrderNumber));
}
```

By using above piece of code it is removing all the data from the JSON file instead of removing required data.Please guide me.

Comment: You haven't populated `JsonDataList`. So, that `Remove` line is not removing anything, because the list is already empty. You can change the `var result = ...` line to `JsonDataList = ...`. However, Rajnik Patel's anwer is more succinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use deserialize the string into objects. Then use Linq to select the wanted items and then use Json.NET again to get the JSON string.

```
    public class Item
    {
       public string applicationName {get; set;}
       public string machineName {get;set;}
       public string OrderNumber {get; set;}
    }

var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(JsonString);

var newJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items.Where(i => i.OrderNumber != "D46364636"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rajnik. But could you please tell me what will be the type of i and why we are using this like this inside where condition?
I am actually new to JSON so it will be help for me to understand.

Comment: It's the syntax of a Lambda expression. The argument to pass (parameter) is on the left of the => and the method(s) that use it are on the right hand side of it.